# Iphone 5c Activation Lock

Tags: iphone

Will the person that pays my Iphone contract need to be with me when i have my Activation Lock removed from my phone? I'm confused as they asked for a proof of purchase letter and ID and when my mum went they said that they needed the 'Original Owner'to be there and i don't know if they meant me or the contract payer - (My Grandad)
I have also tried taking it to other shops but nobody knows what to do
 If anyone could help that would be great, Thanks :)

Comment: If this is your Activation Lock, why would you need to have it removed by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Original owner refers to the first person that payed for the phone, and in this case —although not very clear from your explanation— the person whose Apple ID is tied to the Activation Lock. If on contract, and not unlocked, usually the contract subscriber.